# Why java has no not function/ alternatives for same

Tags: java, code-readability

Ok so if you want to check if a list is not empty

we would need to do something like

`if(! mylist.isEmpty())`

this affects code readability, so how can we write the same thing in a readable way, calling out negation of condition check.

One of possibility is to have a static helper function like:

```
static boolean not(boolean condition) { return !condition;}
```

How bad is this idea? Are there other options in apache common or guava etc? Or any other way you have achieved this?

Comment: What is _unreadable_ about a simple negation?

Comment: its simple in this case what if orginal function on collection was list.isNotEmpty() and I am negating using ! sign. If there are nested braces that would make it less readable.

Comment: I agree its not that it is unreadable as I mentioned affects readablity, again which depends on indvidual.

Comment: use [`CollectionUtils#isNotEmpty`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#isNotEmpty(java.util.Collection)) ?

Comment: Don't you think if `!` is that much useless that even cannot be used here, so what's it made for at all?

Comment: Java (and C, and C++, and ...) doesn't *need* a 'not' function. It has a 'not' *operator.* You may not like how it is spelt, or looks, but you don't introduce redundancy into programming languages; at least not when you know what you're doing when you design it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a bad idea in itself and it will not affect anything. 
However I think many people will disagree with you regarding the "unreadability" of the normal way of negating things using `!`.

`if ( ! list.isEmpty() )`

versus

`if ( not( list.isEmpty() ) )`

does not make much of a difference IMHO.

Comment: In fact first one gives less keystrokes than second one :)

Comment: ...which is a plus, since programmers are lazy ;-)

Comment: ide helps with auto suggest for those things, my point is for readablity...

Comment: @Ankur: every Java developer knows that `!` means `not`, and reads it as "not" in his/her head. Maybe you're not used to it yet, but it will come. Using `not()` decreases readability, because when I read this, I wonder what `not()` might do and I'm forced to check that it's simply a proprietary alias to to standard `!` operator.

Comment: @JBNizet yes you are right we might need to check what not does, tahts why question any of standard lib gives any options, yes what i read ! is again depends on individual hence the question...

Comment: Why would you need a standard API when you have a one-letter standard operator?